# Define instance method of a class after class already defined in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-eval

I have some problem with extending class with instance method after separate module is included into separate class

```
module ActsAsCommentable
  def self.included(commentable)
    Thread.class_eval do
      def commentable
        p "disqusable is #{commentable}"
        p "disqusable class is #{commentable}"
      end
    end
  end
end


class Thread
  #some code...
end

class Asset
  include ActsAsCommentable
end
```

And now I want to call this method somelike this:

```
thread = Thread.new
thread.commentable
```

The problem is, of course is that there is no binding with include method for class eval, and I could save variables that I want to pass into class eval in ActsAsCommentable module, but I dont want to. Is there a better way?

I tried to do instead

```
module ActsAsCommentable
  def self.included(commentable)
    class << Thread
      define_method :commentable do
        p "disqusable is #{commentable}"
        p "disqusable class is #{commentable}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But As I guessed this creates instance method for singletone object of class and therefore I can call it only through

```
Thread.commentable
```

And again, no binding...

Comment: Commentable [Threads](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html)? What is this madness?

You should probably choose a more specific name, which does not conflict with a concurrency mechanism.

Comment: well this is actually working with disqus modules, and there is Thread  entity, and therefore, the question is not about that). In code this module nested in Disqus::Thread, I just dont wanted to pollute example. But you are right in general.

Comment: I know the question is not about it, this is just what I was thinking when reading your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to be able to access the `commentable` variable inside your `Thread` extension, right?

If so, just change this:

```
Thread.class_eval do
```

To this:

```
Thread.class_exec(commentable) do |commentable|
```

And it should work.

Comment: Well actually not really - my question was about creating new method inside Thread class and access commentable inside it - I had to use define method inside of class_exec - because there is changing of contenxt inside def my_new_method.

But it was helpful with class_exec, thanks

Comment: @sandric: Glad to help somehow.